# Macro to copy data from one sheet to another, only if not already present

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with this macro. I have two sheets; One with a large set of data that is updated by a macro with respect to multiple dates.

I want to copy the data from that sheet ("rawdata1") to another sheet ("sheet1"), but only if the data isn't already present (don't want multiple entries of the same data on "sheet1"). I have no problem copying the data to the other sheet but how do you avoid duplicate entries when the macro is run multiple times?

The code I have so far:

```
Sub CopyData()
'Copy data if not present in other sheet
'???

Sheets("rawdata1").Select
Range("A4:AC10000").Select
Range("A4:AC10000").Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  ' Find the last row of data
  FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Your code can be simplified to:

```
Sheets("rawdata1").Range("A4:AC10000").Copy _
      Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)    
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

As for preventing multiple copies of the same line, if you're in Excel 2007+ then you can use RemoveDuplicates after running the copy: this will reduce the range down to unique rows only. Note: you need to adjust the `Columns` parameter to include all relevant column numbers.

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange("$A$1:$E$8").RemoveDuplicates _
    Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes 'or xlNo, depending on your data
```

Comment: A note on this - if you do have multiple rows which are the same in different data imports you will be deleting one of the rows.

Comment: @enderland: good point, and if that's the case then the OP will need to add some additional "key" to the data to prevent that from happening

Comment: + 1 Nice one :) @User1639703: Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: As a very novice programmer it is so simple it is complicated! :) Thanks so much for the help, it makes sense. I will play around with it for a bit and see what I get. Using Excel2007